# Why does the dropdown menu animation cut the height when you hover again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, jquery-animate

I've recently implemented this HTML, CSS and jQuery code from MegaDrop. Like any dropdown menu, it's supposed to show all the links when you hover over it.

Please hover on Products to see the result.

The problem starts when you hover away and when you hover again before the animation is finished, it will cut the height and remembers that. It will also not respond after you hover on and off a couple of times. Which is odd.

I've set no height in the container. I just let it render natively since the links have padding.

The container has **overlay: hidden** as well.

To enable the jQuery animation I need to remove **display: block** from **.nav > li:hover > div**

My question is, how do I prevent this? Do I need to give more instructions to the jQuery itself in order to retain the height of the container and not to shorten it?

This is the site:
http://planet.nu/dev/test/index.html

Here are my HTML, CSS and Javascript:

```js
$(function(){
 $('.animated > li').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('div[class^="container-"]').stop().slideDown('fast');
 },
 function(){
  $(this).find('div[class^="container-"]').stop().slideUp('slow');
 });
});
```

```css
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}


body { font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif; background: #f5f5f5; font-size: 100%;}
a { color: #666; text-decoration: none;}

.nav {
 background: #666;
 border-radius: 3px;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 height: 43px;
}

.nav li { list-style: none;  }
.nav > li { padding: 0; float: left; position: relative; }
.nav > li > a {
 float: left;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-decoration: none;
 line-height: 43px;
 padding: 0 20px; 
 border-right: 1px solid #777;
 border-left: 1px solid #555;
 height: 43px;
}
.nav > li:hover > a { background: #555; border-right: 1px solid #666; }
.nav > li:first-child > a { border-left: 0; }
.nav > li:last-child > a { border-right: 0; }
.nav > li:hover > div {  }

/* MEGA DROP DOWN */

.nav > li > div {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 43px;
 display: none;
 background: #fff;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 overflow: hidden;
}
.nav > li > div p { color: #666; }
.nav > li > div.right { right: 0; left: auto }
.container-1, .container-2, .container-3, .container-4 { font-size: 80%; }


/* COLUMNS */
.col1,.col2,.col3,.col4,.col5 { margin: 10px 0; float: left; padding: 0 10px;}


 /* 1 Column */
 .container-1 { width: 170px; }
 .container-1 .col1 { width: 100%; }

 /* 2 Column */
 .container-2 { width: 270px; }
 .container-2 .col1 { width: 50% }
 .container-2 .col2 { width: 100% }

 /* 3 Column */
 .container-3 { width: 400px; }
 .container-3 .col1 { width: 33.33% }
 .container-3 .col2 { width: 66.66% }
 .container-3 .col3 { width: 100% }


 /* 4 Column */
 .container-4 { width: 500px; }
 .container-4 .col1 { width: 25%; }
 .container-4 .col2 { width: 50% }
 .container-4 .col3 { width: 75% }
 .container-4 .col4 { width: 100% }


 /* 5 Column */
 .container-5 { width: 600px; }
 .container-5 .col1 { width: 20%; }
 .container-5 .col2 { width: 40% }
 .container-5 .col3 { width: 60% }
 .container-5 .col4 { width: 80% }
 .container-5 .col5 { width: 100% }

/* HIGHLIGHTS */

.container-3 .highlighted { 
 width: 400px; 
 margin-left: -20px; 
 padding: 20px; 
 background: #e4fbff; 
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.container-4 .highlighted { 
 width: 500px;
 margin-left: -10px; 
 padding: 20px; 
 background: #e4fbff; 
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}



.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Mega Drop Down</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/megadrop.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav clearfix animated">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Products</a>
  <div class="container-4">
   <div class="col1">
    <h3>Vegetables</h3>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Tomatoes</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Squash</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Zucchini</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cucumbers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Green Beans</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lima Beans</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col1">
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blueberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cranberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Raspberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Strawberries</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
    <h3>Quality Guaranteed</h3>
    <p>We stand behind our products and guarantee you will get high quality products.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col4 highlighted">
    <h3>SALE: Buy one get one FREE</h3>
    <p>All of our products are buy one get one free until April 1, 2013.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col1">
    <h3>Vegetables</h3>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Tomatoes</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Squash</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Zucchini</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cucumbers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Green Beans</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lima Beans</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col1">
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blueberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cranberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Raspberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Strawberries</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
    <h3>Quality Guaranteed</h3>
    <p>We stand behind our products and guarantee you will get high quality products.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col4 highlighted">
    <h3>SALE: Buy one get one FREE</h3>
    <p>All of our products are buy one get one free until April 1, 2013.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col4">
    <h3>Quality Guaranteed</h3>
    <p>We stand behind our products and guarantee you will get high quality products.</p>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <div class="container-1 right">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Why We Care</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some other page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How We Work</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I created the three files, added the stylesheet link, and the page displays nothing.  Can you provide a fully working HTML file instead of just part of it?

Comment: Allow me to revise the question.

Comment: Question has been revised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Looks like `animate` leaves some residual values in your `div` when its interrupted (inspections using firebug clearly shows this). Clearing it up before you start the animation should fix it.

`$(this).find('div[class^="container-"]').attr("style","").stop().slideDown('fast');`

```js
$(function(){
 $('.animated > li').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('div[class^="container-"]').attr("style","").stop().slideDown('fast');
 },
 function(){
  $(this).find('div[class^="container-"]').stop().slideUp('slow');
 });
});
```

```css
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}


body { font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif; background: #f5f5f5; font-size: 100%;}
a { color: #666; text-decoration: none;}

.nav {
 background: #666;
 border-radius: 3px;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 height: 43px;
}

.nav li { list-style: none;  }
.nav > li { padding: 0; float: left; position: relative; }
.nav > li > a {
 float: left;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-decoration: none;
 line-height: 43px;
 padding: 0 20px; 
 border-right: 1px solid #777;
 border-left: 1px solid #555;
 height: 43px;
}
.nav > li:hover > a { background: #555; border-right: 1px solid #666; }
.nav > li:first-child > a { border-left: 0; }
.nav > li:last-child > a { border-right: 0; }
.nav > li:hover > div {  }

/* MEGA DROP DOWN */

.nav > li > div {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 43px;
 display: none;
 background: #fff;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 overflow: hidden;
}
.nav > li > div p { color: #666; }
.nav > li > div.right { right: 0; left: auto }
.container-1, .container-2, .container-3, .container-4 { font-size: 80%; }


/* COLUMNS */
.col1,.col2,.col3,.col4,.col5 { margin: 10px 0; float: left; padding: 0 10px;}


 /* 1 Column */
 .container-1 { width: 170px; }
 .container-1 .col1 { width: 100%; }

 /* 2 Column */
 .container-2 { width: 270px; }
 .container-2 .col1 { width: 50% }
 .container-2 .col2 { width: 100% }

 /* 3 Column */
 .container-3 { width: 400px; }
 .container-3 .col1 { width: 33.33% }
 .container-3 .col2 { width: 66.66% }
 .container-3 .col3 { width: 100% }


 /* 4 Column */
 .container-4 { width: 500px; }
 .container-4 .col1 { width: 25%; }
 .container-4 .col2 { width: 50% }
 .container-4 .col3 { width: 75% }
 .container-4 .col4 { width: 100% }


 /* 5 Column */
 .container-5 { width: 600px; }
 .container-5 .col1 { width: 20%; }
 .container-5 .col2 { width: 40% }
 .container-5 .col3 { width: 60% }
 .container-5 .col4 { width: 80% }
 .container-5 .col5 { width: 100% }

/* HIGHLIGHTS */

.container-3 .highlighted { 
 width: 400px; 
 margin-left: -20px; 
 padding: 20px; 
 background: #e4fbff; 
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.container-4 .highlighted { 
 width: 500px;
 margin-left: -10px; 
 padding: 20px; 
 background: #e4fbff; 
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}



.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Mega Drop Down</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/megadrop.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav clearfix animated">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Products</a>
  <div class="container-4">
   <div class="col1">
    <h3>Vegetables</h3>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Tomatoes</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Squash</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Zucchini</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cucumbers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Green Beans</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lima Beans</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col1">
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blueberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cranberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Raspberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Strawberries</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
    <h3>Quality Guaranteed</h3>
    <p>We stand behind our products and guarantee you will get high quality products.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col4 highlighted">
    <h3>SALE: Buy one get one FREE</h3>
    <p>All of our products are buy one get one free until April 1, 2013.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col1">
    <h3>Vegetables</h3>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Tomatoes</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Squash</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Zucchini</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cucumbers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Green Beans</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lima Beans</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col1">
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blueberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cranberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Raspberries</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Strawberries</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
    <h3>Quality Guaranteed</h3>
    <p>We stand behind our products and guarantee you will get high quality products.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col4 highlighted">
    <h3>SALE: Buy one get one FREE</h3>
    <p>All of our products are buy one get one free until April 1, 2013.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col4">
    <h3>Quality Guaranteed</h3>
    <p>We stand behind our products and guarantee you will get high quality products.</p>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <div class="container-1 right">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Why We Care</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some other page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How We Work</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a better solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about JavaScript to explain the intricate details, but you have to pass parameters to the stop() method to make the previous animation complete.

```
$(function(){
    $('.animated > li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('div[class^="container-"]').stop(null, true).slideDown('fast');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('div[class^="container-"]').stop().slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```